# How can I stop 0 from appearing in my array

Tags: c#, .net

So I have a method which returns an array of the factors of a number

`Tools.cs`

```
public static long[] GetFactors(long number)
{
    long range = number / 2;
    long potentialFactors = 2;
    long[] factors = new long[range + 1];
    factors[0] = 1;
    factors[range] = number;
    for (long i = 1; i < range; i++)
    {
        if (number % potentialFactors == 0)
        {
            factors[i] = potentialFactors;
            potentialFactors++;
        } else
        {
            potentialFactors++;
        }    
    }
    Console.WriteLine($"here are the factors for the number {number}:\n"+string.Join("\n", factors));
    return factors;
}
```

`program.cs`

```
static void Main(string[] args)
{
    Tools.GetFactors(24);        
    Console.ReadLine();
}
```

But when I run my code, this appears:

```
here are the factors for the number 24:
1
2
3
4
0
6
0
8
0
0
0
12
24
```

How can I stop 0 from appearing, should I rewrite the "for" loop, or is there a way to remove 0 from the array?

Comment: You increment `i` on every loop iteration, but you don't always assign a value to `factors[i]`. On the loops where you don't assign anything, it will keep its default value of 0. Try using a `List<long>` instead of an array, and just `.Add` to it whenever you find a new factor.

Answer (score 2):

You are allocating a fixed size array and setting the element to non-zero only when it is a factor.

You should instead use a `var factors = new List<long>();` and call `factors.Add(potentialFactor);` to only store those numbers which are valid factors.

Comment: That's correct. Though given the strong homework vibes, either should be good. Edited anyone to match expectations.

Comment: using a list instead of an array takes an awfully long amount of time, i previously used lists but it spent 30 mins, and didnt even output anything, so using an array woul be good, i think the solution is to set the element on the array when it's not a factor, but i dont know what to write in the else statement

Comment: It doesn't! Your program appears to have some other bug too where it most probably goes into an infinite loop or something. Try running it under a debugger to see what's going on.

Comment: I decided to let the code run with the debugger on, and it took around 45 mins to print the array, although it found the largest factor at the 20 minutes mark, but it had to loop until it hit the value of range, i guess i have to optimize the for loop or something

Answer (score 0):

This code is using `List` instead of `Array` and also there are some other changes.

```
public static List<long> GetFactors(long number)
{
    long range = number / 2;
    List<long> factors = new List<long>() { 1 };
    for (long i = 2; i <= range; i++)
    {
        if (number % i == 0)
        {
            factors.Add(i);
        }
    }
    factors.Add(number);
    Console.WriteLine($"here are the factors for the number {number}:\n" + string.Join("\n", factors));
    return factors;
}
```

Answer (score 0):

I agree a list is better when you dont know before hand how many factors you will gote. But if you really want to use an Array. You can loop throught this array, find the 0's one by one and them swith Left the numbers. Like so :

```
// Extension Method of array
      public static void RemoveAllZeros(this long[] array) // O(N^2)
            { 
                for (int i = 0; i < array.Length; i++)
                {
                    if (array[i] == 0)
                    {
                        // Grab the index override value and continue swift left
                        for (int j = i; j < array.Length - 1; j++)
                        {
                            array[j] = array[j + 1];
                        } 
                    }
                }
            }


OR using a bit of LINQ and List :p : 
       // Extension Method of array
    public static void RemoveAllZeros(this long[] numbers)
        {
            int zeroPst = numbers.ToList().IndexOf(0); 
    
            if (zeroPst == -1)
                return;
    
            for (int i = zeroPst; i < numbers.Length - 1; i++)
            {
                numbers[i] = numbers[i + 1];
            }
    
            numbers.RemoveAllZeros(); //Recursion, carefull
        }
```